# blank space JSF not rendered components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following code:

```
    <h:form id="mainForm">

      <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="containers" layout="block">

                    <p:outputLabel for="document" value="Document" />
                    <p:inputText id="document"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.documento}" readonly="true" />
                    <h:link styleClass="searchLink" value="Search Documents"
                        outcome="searchDigrc.xhtml"></h:link>

                    <!-- #{dIGRCController.digrc.impresn == 'S'} -->
                    <p:outputLabel for="concept" value="Concept" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="concept"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.qconce}"
                        requiredMessage="You must select a Concept" required="true">

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{cCRX1Controller.ccrx1.concepts.entrySet()}"
                            var="concept" itemValue="#{concept.key}"
                            itemLabel="#{concept.value.tbdesc}" />

                        <p:ajax listener="#{dIGRCController.setDropDownSelectedCcrx1}"
                            update="hiddenSections, searchAgentsLink, agenteName, documentValue, containerDocQty, containerMethodPayment" />

                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="todaysDate" value="Date" />
                    <p:inputText id="todaysDate" readonly="true"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.fecha}" />
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="containers" layout="block">

                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:outputLabel for="agenteName" value="Agent Name" />
                        <p:inputText id="agenteName"
                            readonly="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 'D'}"
                            value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.nombre}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="You must enter an Agent Name" />
                        <h:panelGroup id="searchAgentsLink">
                            <h:link styleClass="searchLink" value="Search Agents"
                                rendered="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 'D'}"
                                outcome="searchAgex1">

                                <f:param name="concept" value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.qconce}" />

                                <c:if test="#{not empty dIGRCController.digrc.documento}">
                                    <f:param name="documento"
                                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.documento}" />
                                </c:if>

                            </h:link>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="documentValue" value="Document Value" />
                    <p:inputText id="documentValue"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.documVal}" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="You must enter a Document Value"
                        validatorMessage="The Document Value must be greater than 0"
                        readonly="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 9 or 
                        dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 1 or 
                        dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 'F'}">

                        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.01" />

                        <p:ajax event="change" update="containerIdTwo"></p:ajax>

                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="containers" layout="block"
                        id="containerDocQty">
                        <h:panelGroup
                            rendered="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.pideqtysn == 'S'}">

                            <p:outputLabel for="documentQuantity" value="Document Quantity" />
                            <p:inputText id="documentQuantity"
                                value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.qtyDoc}" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="You must enter a Document Quantity" />

                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                </h:panelGroup>

            </p:panelGrid>

      <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" id="hiddenSections">

        <h:panelGroup styleClass="containers" layout="grid" id="moneyOrder"
            rendered="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 1}">

            <h2>Money Orders</h2>

            <p:outputLabel for="moneyOrdersQty" value="Quantity" />
            <p:inputText id="moneyOrdersQty"
                value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.moqty}" />

            <p:outputLabel for="moneyOrdersVal" value="Value" />
            <p:inputText id="moneyOrdersVal"
                value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.moval}">

                <p:ajax update="documentValue" event="change"
                    listener="#{dIGRCController.setDocValueToMoneyOrderValue()}" />

            </p:inputText>

        </h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup styleClass="containers" layout="block"
                    rendered="#{dIGRCController.digrc.selectedDropDownCcrx1.tbqcon == 8}">

                    <h2>Transfer Documents</h2>

                    <p:outputLabel for="numeroConduce" value="Transfer Number" />
                    <p:inputText id="numeroConduce"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.notransf}" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="You must enter a Number." />

                    <p:outputLabel for="suplidor" value="Supplier" />
                    <p:inputText id="suplidor" value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.c8supli}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="You must enter a Supplier" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="tipoEnvio" value="Type of Transfer" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoEnvio"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.c8tpenvio}"
                        requiredMessage="You must select a Type of Transfer"
                        required="true">

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Regular" itemValue="R" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Official" itemValue="O" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Express Regular" itemValue="E" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Express Official" itemValue="F" />

                        <p:ajax event="change" update="containerExtraEnvio"></p:ajax>

                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="envioDestino" value="Destination" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="envioDestino"
                        value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.c8destino}"
                        requiredMessage="You must select a Destination" required="true">

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Capital" itemValue="C" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Interior" itemValue="I" />

                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:panelGroup id="containerExtraEnvio">
                        <h:panelGroup
                            rendered="#{dIGRCController.digrc.c8tpenvio == 'O' or dIGRCController.digrc.c8tpenvio == 'F'}">

                            <p:outputLabel for="envioAdicionales" value="Extra" />
                            <p:inputText id="envioAdicionales"
                                value="#{dIGRCController.digrc.c8qadi}" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="You must enter an Extra" />

                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                </h:panelGroup>

      </p:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
```

Inside the first panelGrid, there is an drop down with ID **concept**. When an item is selected, this will update the container with ID **hiddenSections**. If the concept selected is 1, then it should show Money Orders. If the concept is 8, it should show Transfer Documents (see the panelGrid with id hiddenSections).

The image below shows the seven DIV elements that are empty inside. For code clarity, I am only showing two of them (If you wanted to, you should be able to reproduce with two).

Those seven DIV elements represent seven panelGroups that are rendered given the conditions I explained above. When the user first gets to the screen, none of them are rendered because the **concept** is not yet set. In this case, I see empty spaces which I don't want. How do I get rid of those empty spaces?

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce, probably the cause is in the code somewhere else.

Comment: You won't be able to reproduce with the code I entered because I didn't put all the containers in there. Do you want me to put the entire code?

Comment: @Geinmachi I modified my question to make it clearer.

Comment: What is the use of postimg code ifbwe won"t be able to reproduce with it? Amd then you edit your question but omly add what is rendered... how can we even try to reproduce or find a cause then?

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated the question to make it more clear (If you are satisfied, remove the -1 please)

Comment: You have 570 reputation. You must know about [mcve] I assume... please make it so.

Comment: Simply adding `rendered="#{false}"` (instead of conditions) to `h:panelGroup`s in `p:panelGrid id="hiddenSections"` **doesn't** produce empty divs for me. (I assume in your screen divs have content because of `...` between them).

Comment: So your question is how to get rid of empty space that you think are generated by your panelGroup ? (they aren't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case, I see empty spaces which I don't want. How do I get rid of those empty spaces?

Your question is vague and I understood it 3 ways ( excuse me if I misunderstood as the answers seems obvious in all cases ).

1. When a component is not rendered, it doesn't figure in the html at all. So if by empty space you meant space characters then those are outside the tags in question.
2. If the table generated takes space because of css you want that part to be empty at page load then you can use rendered for that.
3. I think that one is what you were asking: Since your selectItem is initially null, none of the panelGroup out of the 8 are rendered and you'd like a default one to be rendered when the selected item is at null. Then just include a check to see if the value is empty for your default panelGroup.

Sorry if I misunderstood the question.